# Cells are not staggered in using RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am developing an Android app. I am not good in Android development. In my app, I am using RecyclerView and CardView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Because I want each cell size in the list different to each other and staggered like in below image.

[image]

But when I run my app, cells are not staggered and they are equal in size to each other.

This is screenshot

[image]

This is my recycler view XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/df_rv_destination"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is XML for cell item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/di_iv_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/di_tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is how I configure my RecyclerView with StaggerGridLayoutManager

```
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
        rcDestinations.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
        rcDestinations.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        regionsList = new ArrayList<Region>();
        destinationsAdapter = new DestinationsAdapter(getActivity(),regionsList);
        rcDestinations.setAdapter(destinationsAdapter);
```

So why is my RecyclerView not staggered? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

set your imageview with `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14080377)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MoralesBatovski

Answer (score 1):

Your cell items all got the same size because there is nothing that would change size... I guess you want to get bigger items if you got bigger pics

First of all change this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

then instead of:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/di_iv_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

try:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/di_iv_image"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and scale the images height to your wished size before adding them ;)
with cropCenter you always get the images cropped to the same size

666

Comment: If I set image scaleType to center, image width will not match to cell width. Alignments will not be proper. Especially with texts.

Comment: Yeah thats right, but you have to scale at least the images height before adding it to the imageView. Could you show me the part of the code where you add the pictures?

Comment: Nothing special. I just directly set the image using picasso. No modification.

Comment: But staggerd layout itself have that kind of feature. Right?

Comment: Yes it has! The problem is that you got big pictures and if you don't scale them in height you got a lot of pixels in height e.g. 600 (well looks ugly) so you have to scale at least the picture. If you scale it with centerCrop it will be cropped to the size of the cell. Try to set scaleY to 0.5 for example to scale to half height

Answer (score -1):

You need to force height resizing to have the effect you wanted.

I am using data binding so, a set the height like this:

```
public int getHeight(int position) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomHeight = r.nextInt(Math.abs(mRecyclerViewHeight)/9) + Math.abs(mRecyclerViewHeight)/4;
    if(position%2 == 0){
        randomHeight += Math.abs(mRecyclerViewHeight)/9;
    }
    return randomHeight;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        ((DiscoveryViewHolder) holder).bindRepository(mPostList.get(position), getHeight(position));
```

holder).bindRepository(mPostList.get(position));
    }

Comment: What is mRecyclerViewHeight value or how to get it?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. mRecyclerViewHeight is hight of recycler view component in your layout.